# Algorithm finding maximum of array O(log n)?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

Does there exist an algorithm that can output the maximum value of an array in O(log n) time? An O(n) algorithm is quite obvious:

1.

> Iterate through all elements

2. 

> If the element is larger than the current maximum, set that as the maximum

But I would want to know if an O(log n) algorithm exists. The same proof of the lower bound* O(n log n) on sorting doesn't seem to apply here. If there exist one, is there an example? If there does not, is there a proof?

*: Yes, I am looking for a comparison-based algorithm, although any algorithm would work, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there is a correct algorithm that on some array of $n$ elements does less than $\frac{n}{2}$ comparisons. Then it didn't compare some element at position $i$ with any other.

Then, if we have another array that differs from our only in position $i$, the algorithm will give the same result. Setting $i$-th element to current maximum + 1 we get an array on which our algorithm works incorrectly.

So, any algorithm that works correctly makes at least $\frac{n}{2}$ comparisons on $n$-elements array.

With slightly more effort it can be shown that actual number of comparisons needed is at least $n - 1$, but it doesn't affect asymptotic.

In general, most problems (finding maximum included) require to at least read input, so have no $o(n)$ algorithm.

Comment: Ahh, I see. In the last line you meant O(log n)? I think Binary search is an exception only because the input must be sorted.

Comment: I mean $o(n)$. There are a lot of functions between $\log n$ and $n$. Yes, binary search doesn't need to read (whole) input. There are also some probabilistic algorithms for some problems that can work with high probability reading like $\sqrt{n}$ or even $O(1)$ bits from input, but they are much less common.

Comment: But $O(n)$ includes $\Theta(n)$, right?

Comment: Yes, but $\Theta$ wasn't mention anywhere in this question before. $o$ and $\Theta$ are different things: $f = o(g)$ means for any $c > 0$, $f(x) < cg(x)$ for all large enough $x$, while $f = \Theta(g)$ means for some $c_1, c_2 > 0$ for all large enough $x$, $c_1 g(x) \leq f(x) \leq c_2 g(x)$.